# How to get a Video Thumbnail using PowerShell on SharePoint SE version?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint (Subscription Edition) document library that is hosting some videos I uploaded. How can I get the video thumbnails using PowerShell? Again, the SharePoint version I am targeting is the Subscription Edition so using Graph is not supported. Any idea how to do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-thumbnails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with CSOM/PowerShell/Rest?

JP